# Uncaught Error: [Navigate] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>

Tags: reactjs

Uncaught Error: [Navigate] is not a  component. All component children of  must be a  or <React.Fragment>
[how to solve this problem?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1mrc.png)
anyone help me i have a this error how to solve this error ? reactjs ecommorece project i building

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to make it so if none of the routes match, then the app navigates to `"/"`? Also, what version of react-router are you using?